# apt-get dist-upgrade problem

Tags: 12.04, apt, upgrade, dpkg

When i try to "`apt-get dist-upgrade`" i always receive the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-virtual : Depends: linux-image-virtual (= 3.2.0.87.101) but 3.2.0.94.108 is installed
                 Depends: linux-headers-virtual (= 3.2.0.87.101) but 3.2.0.94.108 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

when i try "`apt-get -f install`" i receive:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-virtual:
 linux-virtual depends on linux-image-virtual (= 3.2.0.87.101); however:
  Version of linux-image-virtual on system is 3.2.0.94.108.
 linux-virtual depends on linux-headers-virtual (= 3.2.0.87.101); however:
  Version of linux-headers-virtual on system is 3.2.0.94.108.
dpkg: error processing linux-virtual (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-virtual
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Help Please,

Comment: Remove conflicting packages ( `linux-image-virtual` and `linux-headers-virtual`)and try again

Comment: how to know which packages are conflicting?